# Jquery Animated Tab - revert on mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to adapt Gaya Design's Animated Tabbed Content http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/animated-tabbed-content-with-jquery/ for a navigation menu. I want to have the background verting back to the first tab on mouseout but can't seem to get that working. Below is the Javascript for moving background function:

```
var TabbedContent = {
    init: function() {  
        $(".tab_item").mouseover(function() {
            var background = $(this).parent().find(".moving_bg");
            $(background).stop().animate({
                left: $(this).position()['left']
            }, {
                duration: 300
            });
            TabbedContent.slideContent($(this));
        });
    },
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    TabbedContent.init();
});
```

And here is a link to what I'm trying to achieve. [Link](http://www.stimulatingminds.co.uk/test/slider/slide.html)

Any help on how to get the background to revert to tab one on mouseout will be very much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about triggeting the mouseover event of the first item:

```
$('.tabs').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).find('.tab_item:first').mouseover();
});
```